# PHPMailer AddAttachment from Upload

Tags: upload, phpmailer, email-attachments

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
        include('class.smtp.php');

        $mail             = new PHPMailer();
        $body = file_get_contents('index.php');
        $body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
        //$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                                   // 1 = errors and messages
                                                   // 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
        $mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = "mail@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
        $mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password

        $mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'First Last');

        $mail->AddReplyTo("mail@gmail.pl","First Last");

        $mail->Subject    = "New Event";

        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";



        if ($_FILES['Photo']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {
            $address = "mail@gmail.com";
            $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['Photo']['name']);  
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($_FILES['Photo']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['Photo']['name']);  
            $mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");  

            if(!$mail->Send()) 
            {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }   
            else 
            {
            echo "Message sent!";
            }
        }
```

I think already tried everything. Still don't attach files to mail. Any idea?
Trying to attach photos of size less than 3mb. Already tried attach text, images, audio.
I'm using upload form for this.

E:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_event" action="event.php" method="post" name="new_event">
<p><label for="Photo">Photo </label><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" /><input type="file" name="Photo" value="Sarch" /></p>
<input type="submit" name="next1" value="Add Event" />
</form>
```

Sending email without attachment.

**SOLVED**
Change name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" -> name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value=""

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is your mail not sending at all?  Or just not sending an attachment?

Comment: And can we see the HTML of the form that you are using to post?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and [this code example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).